# Localizing siri donated shortcuts

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I've been taking a look at the documentation for [donating a shortcut to siri](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/donating_shortcuts?language=objc), as well as a few blogposts about it. I've managed to add a shortcut to my app using `NSUserActivity`:

```
let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.myapp.mobile")

activity.title = "Some title"
activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
activity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
activity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Summon my app please"
activity.persistentIdentifier = NSUserActivityPersistentIdentifier(rawValue: "com.myapp.mobile")

view.userActivity = activity
activity.becomeCurrent()
```

But so far I have no clue on how I should go about internationalization on the shortcuts. Should I translate `suggestedInvocationPhrase` and `title` before passing them down to the activity or does Siri handles that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to treat the text you pass to the NSUserActivity just like any other text in your app - localize the text before you pass it to the activity.

Answer (score 2):

You should localize it with the `NSString.deferredLocalizedIntentsString` API ([see docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/3003422-deferredlocalizedintentsstring)) so that the intent uses the proper language when it is displayed to the user. (The user might change the language of the phone in the meantime.)

```
activity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = NSString.deferredLocalizedIntentsString(with: "localization_key_for_your_invocation_phrase") as String
```